# Rails: Building a has_one relationship in a model with Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, has-one

I have a `User` model that has_one `Profile` (belongs_to User). For simplicity I'll just say the profile has a `location` field and an `occupation` field.

I'm using `Omniauth` to create Users but I would also like to create the attached `Profile` at the same time. Currently my `create` from omniauth method is as follows:

```
def self.create_from_omniauth(omniauth_data)
  full_name = omniauth_data["info"]["name"].split(" ")
  User.create(
       provider: omniauth_data["provider"],
       uid: omniauth_data["uid"],
       first_name: full_name[0],
       last_name: full_name[1],
       email: omniauth_data["info"]["email"],
       password: SecureRandom.hex(16)
  )
end
```

I'm wondering how I should include the building of the profile in that. I know with has_one I have access to the `build_profile` method but I also want to ensure that it is properly connected to my User object. Any insight into how I should reformat that `create_from_omniauth` action to properly build the associated `Profile` alongside the `User` object would be extremely helpful.

Comment: There is at least two way to do it and if you change the third line to `user = User.create` you can then do `user.create_profile()`. Of Instead of `User.create` and `user.create_profile` use build and then save it all at once with `user.save`

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to do what you want is use the users#show action for the Profile. Instead of creating a Profile model with a Profile table in the database (wasting of memory), why not just use the show for your users as profile. In that case you can rename the route for your show action as profile.

Comment: My `Profile` model actually handles more than just this simplified example so I need the has_one relationship I can't just include those fields in the `User` model. I'm looking to just build the initial pieces from the `Omniauth` data